# Incorrect alarm raised by pocketsphinx in android

Tags: pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I have implemented pocketsphinx in my my android application to recognize voice command and create some custom dictionary and words to recognize. Here is my implementation:

```
 private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
    recognizer = defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
            //.setRawLogDir(assetsDir)
            .setKeywordThreshold(1e-10f)
            .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)

            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    // Create keyword-activation search.
    // recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

    File menuGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "target-words.gram");
    recognizer.addKeywordSearch(KWS_SEARCH, menuGrammar);

}
```

For words list:

```
yalp /1-0/
yaalp /1-0/
yeelp /1e-1/
yelp /1e-1/
```

and grammar:

```
yalp Y AE L P
yaalp Y AA L P
yealp Y EH L P
yeelp Y IY L P
yelp Y EH L P
```

But i am getting wrong results,means if i am not speaking or make a sound(even on clapping) i am getting onPartialResult like Yelp Yealp etc . I try to tune setKeywordThreshold() // 1e-10f, 1e-20f,1e-30f etc same as for words list to add different range like 1-0/1e-1 but nothing is working to make this correct. Can someone suggest me why this is producing a wrong results..

Here is the image of my asset:
[image]

Comment: Provide logcat output. Uncomment setRawLogDir and provide collected raw data files.

Comment: Here is logcat and raw files: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-_xX0LiBM6PV0E1RHUtYm56OW8&usp=sharing

Comment: There is something wrong with your code, the audio is not recorded properly. Show the full class how do you process onResult

Comment: I have one more observation of pocketPhinx on different devices, When i test this application on android phone(version 5.0.1) it work perfectly on that i means no false alarm from library but when i try to do this on tablet(Lenevo android version 5.1.1) there it actually creates this false alarms. So it make no sense but may be someone experienced this and have a solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Nikolay, I add a voice recognition implementation class(Not complete but stuff related to pocketphnix) https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-_xX0LiBM6PV0E1RHUtYm56OW8&usp=sharing

Comment: Well, it might be device dependent indeed. What exactly Lenovo do you have? What software do you have installed, do you have any other voice application running in background (voice service I see in logcat). It might be a problem with multiple recorders trying to access microphone. You can listen raw files, they just contain clicks.

Comment: I am using Lenovo Yoga tab3. Its a new one and have not installed anything on this. There is no other services/activity accessing the microphone inside my android application. This is strange that creating a problems on this tablet and working on phone. Can you tell me how i can listen these raw files. btw i was in quiet room when i run the application so may be you heard nothing when play audio.

Comment: You can listen files with audacity, they are 16khz 16bit mono pcm files.